# Ambiguous reference to member error when assigning position to SKEmitterNode

Tags: sprite-kit, swift2, skemitternode

I am trying to assign a CGPoint position to a SKEmitterNode

```
// Add the explosive emitter
var pos = CGPointMake(gs.frame.size.height / 2, gs.frame.size.width / 2);


var fireEmitterPath = NSBundle.mainBundle().pathForResource("Fire", ofType: "sks");
var fireEmitter = NSKeyedUnarchiver.unarchiveObjectWithFile(fireEmitterPath!);
fireEmitter?.position = pos; // ERROR HERE 
fireEmitter?.runAction(SKAction.sequence([SKAction.waitForDuration(0.2), SKAction.scaleBy(1.5, duration: 0.1), SKAction.runBlock({ 
    fireEmitter?.particleBirthRate = 0;
})]))

// add the smoke emitter
var smokeEmitterPath = NSBundle.mainBundle().pathForResource("Smoke", ofType: "sks");
var smokeEmitter = NSKeyedUnarchiver.unarchiveObjectWithFile(smokeEmitterPath!);
smokeEmitter?.position = pos;

gs.addChild(smokeEmitter);
smokeEmitter?.runAction(SKAction.sequence([SKAction.waitForDuration(0.2), SKAction.scaleBy(1.2, duration: 0.2), SKAction.runBlock({ 
    smokeEmitter?.particleBirthRate = 0;
})]))
```

When assigning the emitter.position I am getting a compiler error :

> Ambiguous reference to member 'position'

Any input appreciated.

Comment: `unarchiveObjectWithFile` returns unspecified type `AnyObject?`. You have to cast it to the actual type. And all your `var`iables are actually constants (`let`)

Comment: Got it, many thanks